# Is there a built-in function in react-big-calendar that runs when it's a new day?

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I hope you guys are doing well! I was wondering if there was a built-in function in react-big-calendar that runs when it's a new day. For example, if the time is currently 11:59PM and the user is still on the day page, then when it turns 12:00AM, this function would run as it is a new day. I know I can use setTimeout to achieve this, but I was just wondering if there was a function from React-Big-Calendar that I can use. Please let me know!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Big Calendar rerenders layout on state change. There are no internal timers to attempt to automatically update as the system clock changes. Overall layout is very process intensive, managing event layout, scollToTime, the current time indicator, etc, so placing a timer to update state would not be a good idea.